# Как прочитать строку из консоли

Tags: c++

Есть алгоритм для переворота строки.Он переводит только ту строку,которую я укажу в `char string[] = "Hello, world";` Но как сделать так,чтобы он переводил строку,которую я вписал в консоли при запуске программы?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int main()

{

    char string[] = "Hello, world";
    int length = strlen(string);
    int temp,i,j;
    for (i = 0, j = length - 1; i < j; i++,j--)
    {
        temp = string[i];
        string[i] = string[j];
        string[j] = temp;
    }
    std::cout << string << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а проблема то в чём? Прочитать строку `cin.getline` например.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int size = 1000;
char str[size];
std::cin.getline(str, size);
```

Comment: `size` должен быть константой времени компиляции. Иначе нужна поддержка VLA. А это не стандартное поведение.